# Cover a polygonal line using the least given rectangles while keeping her continuity

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Given a **list of points** forming a polygonal line, and both **height** and **width** of a rectangle, how can I find the **number** and **positions** of all rectangles needed to cover all the points?

The rectangles should be rotated and may overlap, but must follow the path of the polyline (A rectangle may contain multiple segments of the line, but each rectangle must contain a segment that is contiguous with the previous one.)

Do the intersections on the smallest side of the rectangle, when it is possible, would be much appreciated.

All the solutions I found so far were not clean, here is the result I get:

[image: Actual Render]

You should see that it gives a good render in near-flat cases, but overlaps too much in big curbs. One rectangle could clearly be removed if the previous were offset.

Actually, I put a rectangle centered at **width/2** along the line and rotate it using *convex hull* and modified *rotating calipers* algorithms, and reiterate starting at the intersection point of the previous rectangle and the line.

You may observe that I took inspiration from the *minimum oriented rectangle bounding box* algorithm, for the orientation, but it doesn't include the cutting aspect, nor the fixed size.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I assume you are looking for a solution covering your polyline with the minimum number of rectangles, correct?

Comment: @SaiBot That's correct, but as stated, all the rectangles must respect the given size. (I aleady found dozens of posts about non-fixed rectangles)
And in my case, viewability is more important than quantity. That's why I prefer to cut on the smallest sides of the square when it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a little late and you’ve probably figured this out. But, I was free today and worked on the constraint reflected in your last edit (continuity of segments). As I said before in the comments, I suggest using a greedy algorithm. It’s composed of two parts:

1. A search algorithm that looks for furthermost point from an initial point (I used [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)), so that all points between them lie inside a rectangle of given `w` and `h`.
2. A repeated loop that finds best rectangle at each step and advances the initial point.

The pseudo code of them are like these respectively:

```
function getBestMBR( P, iFirst, w, h )
    nP = length(P);
    iStart = iFirst;
    iEnd = nP;
    while iStart <= iEnd
        m = floor((iStart + iEnd) / 2);
        MBR = getMBR(P[iFirst->m]);
        if (MBR.w < w) & (MBR.h < h) {*}
            iStart = m + 1;
            iLast = m;
            bestMBR = MBR;
        else
            iEnd = m - 1;
        end
    end
    return bestMBR, iLast;
end

function getRectList( P, w, h )
    nP = length(P);
    rects = [];
    iFirst = 1;
    iLast = iFirst;
    while iLast < nP
        [bestMBR, iLast] = getBestMBR(P, iFirst, w, h);
        rects.add(bestMBR.x, bestMBR.y, bestMBR.a];
        iFirst = iLast;
    end
    return rects;
```

Solution for test case 1: 
[image]

Solution for test case 2: 
[image]

Just keep in mind that it’s not meant to find the optimal solution, but finds a sub-optimal one in a reasonable time. It’s [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) after all.

Another point is that you can improve this a little in order to decrease number of rectangles. As you can see in the line marked with `(*)`, I kept resulting rectangle in direction of MBR ([Minimum Bounding Rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms)), even though you can cover larger MBRs with rectangles of same `w` and `h` if you rotate the rectangle. ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847282/fitting-rectangle-inside-another-rectangle-in-diagonal)) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784274/detect-if-one-rect-can-be-put-into-another-rect))

Comment: It's not that late, I finished it following some of your advices, but I'm still up to optimize some parts, and your code just helped me to spot a specific case that could make the last rectangle not result as intended.
Thanks for your work, I mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I modified [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) to solve this. It's not fast, it's not optimal, it's not guaranteed, but (IMHO) it's a good start.
There are two important modifications:

**1- The distance measure**

I used a [Chebyshev-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)-inspired measure to see how far points are from each rectangle. To find distance from points to each rectangle, first I transformed all points to a new coordinate system, shifted to center of rectangle and rotated to its direction:

[image: Transformation of original data to coordinate system of rectangle]

Then I used these transformed points to calculate distance:

```
d = max(2*abs(X)/w, 2*abs(Y)/h);
```

It will give equal values for all points that have same distance from each side of rectangle. The result will be less than `1.0` for points that lie inside rectangle. Now we can classify points to their closest rectangle.

**2- Strategy for updating cluster centers**

Each cluster center is a combination of `C`, center of rectangle, and `a`, its rotation angle. At each iteration, new set of points are assigned to a cluster. Here we have to find `C` and `a` so that rectangle covers maximum possible number of points. I don’t now if there is an analytical solution for that, but I used a statistical approach. I updated the `C` using weighted average of points, and used direction of first [principal component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) of points to update `a`. I used results of proposed distance, powered by 500, as weight of each point in weighted average. It moves rectangle towards points that are located outside of it.

**How to Find K**

Initiate it with 1 and increase it till all distances from points to their corresponding rectangles become less than 1.0, meaning all points are inside a rectangle.

**The results**

Iterations 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, and 50 of updating cluster centers (rectangles):
[image: Iterations]

Solution for test case 1:
[image]

Trying Ks: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, and 12 for complete coverage:
[image: Different Ks]

Solution for test case 2:
[image]

**P.M:** I used parts of [Chalous Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_59_(Iran)) as data. It was fun downloading it from [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/36.1810023,51.3184726/36.2784168,51.2438858/@36.2168112,51.2885177,12z). The I used technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27430360/2093077) to sample a set of equally spaced points.

Comment: Thanks for your work @saastn!
This is very similar to what I'm looking for, except that all rectangles must only contain one segment.

I was actually trying another approach that seems to be cleaner than what I had, except that it handles less tricky cases.

I will try to impement your solution, and see where I must implement this condition.

Comment: My previous comment may lead to bad interpretation, I will rephrase :
Rectangles may contain multiple segments of the line, but each rectangle must contain a segment that is contiguous with the previous one.
For example, in your testcase n°2, 2nd rectangle is also the 4th if you follow the path, I have to avoid this behaviour. Any hits about how to do it?

Comment: That's an important constraint @ChrisProlls. You should include that in your question. Now, I think your approach is OK, except for step length (Width/2). You can use a greedy algorithm and try to cover as more points as possible at each iteration. That needs a search algorithm, and it means lots of ConvexHall and OrientedRectangleBoundingBox calls at each iteration.